# Sql запрос и алиасы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть несколько таблиц, примерно вот такого содержания:

```
+------------------+
| model | category |
+------------------+
+ 10    | 20       +
+ 11    | 20       +
+ 12    | 20       +
+ 13    | 45       +
+ 14    | 45       +
+ 15    | 45       +
+------------------+

+------------------+
| product | cat    |
+------------------+
+ 10      | 20     +
+ 11      | 20     +
+ 12      | 20     +
+ 13      | 45     +
+ 14      | 45     +
+ 15      | 45     +
+------------------+

+--------------+
| view_product |
+--------------+
+ 10           +
+ 11           +
+ 12           +
+ 13           +
+ 14           +
+--------------+
```

Что происходит у меня: при определенном условии выбирается первая или вторая таблица, по которой происходит `LEFT_JOIN` в третью таблицу, т.е.:

```
if(1 == 1) {
    $query_table = "SELECT table_one.model AS item FROM table_one";
}
else {
    $query_table = "SELECT table_two.product AS item FROM table_two";
}
$finish_query = $query_table
. "LEFT JOIN table_three ON (item = table_three.view_product)";
```

Но mysql отдает ошибку, что, мол, `Unknown column 'item' in 'on clause'`.

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75754/1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause/153627#153627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь объявлять алиасы в секции запроса `SELECT`, а использовать их в секции `FROM`. По стандарту sql так делать нельзя, потому что это противоречит порядку исполнения запроса. СУБД исполняет сначала секцию `FROM`, а уже потом `SELECT`. Строго говоря, по стандарту `SELECT` вообще выполняется почти последним. После него только группировка и сортировка. Вот как раз в `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` и `HAVING` алиасы столбцов, объявленные в секции `SELECT` использовать можно. Это правило верно не только для MySQL, но для всех СУБД, реализующих стандартный sql.

Answer (score 0):

А если так написать работает?

```
if(1 == 1) {
   $query_table = "SELECT table_one.model FROM table_one LEFT JOIN table_three ON table_one.model = table_three.view_product";
}
else {
    $query_table = "SELECT table_two.product FROM table_two LEFT JOIN table_three ON table_two.product = table_three.view_product";
}
```

Comment: Ввел ваш вариант с подстановкой на ideone.com выдал "успешно". Так что возможно у вас пропущен пробел перед LEFT JOIN

Comment: @MDJHD нет, не в пробеле дело, просто пример на коленке писал. 
Если подставлять колонки, как предложили вы - то конечно работает.

Comment: Ну так, как говорится, Гугль вам в помощь :))) Смотрите здесь http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13551 и здесь http://petrenco.com/mysql.php?txt=52